# Xamarin.Forms sqlite-net-pcl does not fill query result with values

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net-pcl

I am working with Visual Studio Mac 8.3.2 and Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0 to create an app for iOS and Android. As db interface library I am using sqlite-net-pcl 1.6.292. I tried older versions, but the result is the same.

On iOS everything is working fine. The query is returning the expected results correctly. On Android I am getting the correct number of result records, but the result values are always 0 or empty.

Here some code

```
public class ewCatAbstract
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NoOfObjects { get; set; }
    public string ImageName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ewCatAbstract> GetCategories()
    {
        var fieldName = Globals.dbFieldName(); // returning field name depending on currect language, e.g. nameEng

        var list = Globals.dbConnection.Query<ewCatAbstract>(
            "SELECT ewCat.id, ewCat." + fieldName + " AS Name, COUNT(ewObject2Category.id) AS NoOfObjects, " +
            "CASE WHEN ewCat.id = 2 THEN 'a.png' WHEN ewCat.id = 3 THEN 'b.png' ELSE '?' END AS ImageName " +
            "FROM ewCat, ewObject2Category " +
            "GROUP BY ewCat.id, ewObject2Category.category " +
            "HAVING ewObject2Category.category = ewCat.id " +
            "ORDER BY ewCat.sort");

        // debug code followng
        Console.WriteLine("ewCatAbstract GetCategories: {0} ", list.Count);

        foreach (var element in list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("mybase: Type is {0}", element.GetType());
            Console.WriteLine("id " + element.id);
            Console.WriteLine("name " + element.Name);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

The number of returned records is correct. When running through the loop, I see the correct class type for every returned element, but when printing the "id" and "Name" values, "id" is always 0 and the "Name" string is always an empty string.

The connection to the database can be opened. I do not get any errors here. Otherwise I would not get the correct number of results.
Please note: the code is working correctly on iOS. It is failing under Android. Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

More Info:
The sqlite database is a pre-populated database. I copied the database file into the 'Assets' folder and open it via the following code.

```
public SQLite.SQLiteConnection CreateConnection()
{
    var sqliteFilename = AppResources.EwAppDatabase; // fetching file name from AppResources
    string documentsDirectoryPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    var path = Path.Combine(documentsDirectoryPath, sqliteFilename);

    // This is where we copy in our pre-created database
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(global::Android.App.Application.Context.Assets.Open(sqliteFilename)))
        {
            using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create)))
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                int length = 0;
                while ((length = binaryReader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    binaryWriter.Write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);

    return conn;
}
```

I use the database for reading only. I am not writing to it.

Comment: Could you share the code of where you are writing the data? Even sharing the code in a repo would help

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I updated my question with more information.

Comment: Are you sure the database contains the values you expect?

Comment: Yes! 1st: the number of results is correct. 2nd: the same database file works with iOS. 3rd: the same database file works using the command line client.

Comment: @mschmitt Do you use `CreateTable<Type>()` to create the table? If no, please check the PrimaryKey data type. And try to use `[PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]`.